# Set wallpaper from image url using cordova

Tags: ionic-framework

I have gone through lot of googling and have tried numerous ways to set the wallpaper from an image url.

I did a file transfer and downloaded the image at all locations mentioned here.
http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/

But windows.cordova.wallpaper.setImage() did not set wallpaper from any location.

But when i placed the image in ionic's www/img folder and gave path to setImage function as 'img/image1.png', then it set the image as wallpaper.

Please help as i am losing hope dealing with it.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible that you are checking it while doing `ionic run android`. If so, try copy-paste the build apk to your phone and then try the functionality. I have run into similar issues with file plugin.

Comment: No Harshil, it did not work for me, Also i found a code in android's wallpaper.java file.  There  it is written

InputStream instr = assetManager.open("www/" + image);

So it will always get the image from its assets. But i tried changing the path here by giving something like below,

InputStream instr = assetManager.open(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+image);

Answer (score 0):

I made this working by making change in the wallpaper.java plugin file which was fetching images from our ionic apps folder. Now we are forcing it to pick images from device folder.

> File file = new File("image path in device"); InputStream instr = new
>   FileInputStream(file); bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(instr);
>          WallpaperManager wm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context);
>              wm.setBitmap(bitmap);